# My VB project fails to download an exe file

Tags: vb.net, file, download

I have an update dialog and when the "Direct Download" button is pressed it used to download an exe file from a dropbox location. However, now it just doesn't download the file anymore, and it's meant to launch the file after download but it will say: File Not found.

The code is:

```
Dim TempPath As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) & "\Temp"
    Try
        My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(TempPath & "\animeygocardmaker.exe")
        My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/72383434/animeygocardmaker.exe", TempPath & "\animeygocardmaker.exe")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("An error occured while trying to download the file")
    End Try

    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(TempPath & "\animeygocardmaker.exe")
    Dim CloseAllWindows As New CloseAll
    Form1.Pause()
    CloseAllWindows.CloseAll()
```

And like I said it always used to work. Could the problem be that the file takes too long to download?

Comment: Firstly, is that really well-structured code?  You have the download inside a Try...Catch block so you're acknowledging that it might fail, yet you still call Process.Start to run the file as though it's guaranteed to be there.  Does that make sense?  Also, does it make sense that you are constructing the very same path three times?  Your MsgBox is also next to useless because it tells you that something went wrong with no indication anywhere of what that was.  If an exception is occurring then interrogate that exception to get all the information you can from it.

Comment: yeah I realized now that you said it, I guess I stuck to that code because it always used to work. Thanks for telling me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        Dim TempPath As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) & "\Temp"
    Try
        My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/72383434/animeygocardmaker.exe", TempPath & "\animeygocardmaker.exe")

        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(TempPath & "\animeygocardmaker.exe")
        Dim CloseAllWindows As New CloseAll
        Form1.Pause()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("An error occured while trying to download the file" + ex.ToString)
    End Try
    CloseAllWindows.CloseAll()
```